# Finding infinite unions and intersections of $(1-1/k,2+1/k]$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> Let $S_k=(1-1/k,2+1/k]$, find$$(a)\bigcup_{k\geq1}S_k;\quad(b)\bigcap_{k\geq1}S_k;\quad(c)\bigcup_{k\geq1}S_k^c;\quad(d)\bigcap_{k\geq1}S_k^c.$$

*My solutions:*
\begin{align}
&(a)\,(0,3]; \qquad(b)\,[1,2];\\
&(c)\bigcup_{k\geq1}S_k^c=\left[\bigcap_{k\geq1}S_k\right]^c=[1,2]^c=(-\infty,1)\cup(2,\infty);\\
&(d)\bigcap_{k\geq1}S_k^c=\left[\bigcup_{k\geq1}S_k\right]^c=(0,3]^c=(-\infty,0]\cup(3,\infty).
\end{align}
Would these results be correct?

Comment: Yes.  These are all correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are all correct.

(Answering as community wiki so the question can be marked as answered.)